# How to change iterations in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```
file = ['Tool','Cool','Pool']
word = 'Cool'
guesses = ['T','P']
for i in range(len(file)):
    if len(file[i]) == len(word):
        for j in range(len(file[i])):
            print(file[i][j])
            for k in range(len(guesses)):
                print(guesses[k])
                if file[i][j] == guesses[k]:
                    i + 1
```

In my piece of code, I am having issue moving to the next item in the list `file`. When `file[0][0] == 'T'` and `guesses[0] == 'T'` occurs I would like to move on to the next item in the file list. I figured `i + 1` was suitable but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please define your problem statement in words ?

Comment: basically what im looking for it to do is as follows: I want it to search file[i] for any of the letters in guesses. should it find any of these letters i want file to immediately shift to the next item in the list.

Comment: All that `i + 1` does is calculate the value of `i` added to 1 and then throw away the result. If you want to update the `i` variable you need an assignment statement--either `i += 1` or `i = i + 1`. That calculate the value of `i` added to 1 _and then stores the result in `i`_ instead of just doing nothing with it.

Comment: Also note that if you _do_ modify `i` it will be reset at the top of the loop. See what the following code does in the interactive interpreter: `>>> for i in range(5): ...    print i,; i+=3; print i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is to use `continue`, but since you have a few nested loops it won't work correctly so we can use a helper method to reduce it to one for loop and then use `continue`:

```
def find_any(what, where):
    for that in what:
       if that in where:
           return True
    return False

file = ['Tool','Cool','Pool']
word = 'Cool'
guesses = ['T','P']
for i in range(len(file)):
    if len(file[i]) == len(word) and find_any(guesses, file[i]):
        continue # This will skip to the next file
    # Do things with file[i] here
```

Comment: Except that if that evaluates to false it will continue anyway, surely @MichaelP needs something to happen if it doesn't find a matching letter?

Comment: I'm assuming he figured out that other code goes below the if-statement, but I'll update just to clarify that